# Get objects that are foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I need ot get objects that are foreign keys. Example

```
class City(models.Model):
    .....


class User(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKeu(City)
    .......
```

Can i get only that cities which are Foreign key to model User with django orm or mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, it's all in the Documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/

Provide a readable backward reference to the city model (in your User model change city to this one):

```
city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='user')
```

Then

```
cities = City.objects.select_related('user').filter(user__city__isnull=False).all()
```